# Calculation of a swivel rotation (without physics engine)

Tags: rotation, sprite, game-physics, 2d-games

I try to get the rotation angle of a swiveling wheel, given the rotation angle of the connected body:

[image]

Using wheels angles was my first attempt:i already have this information stored. To get the rotation angle of the wheel, i try to calculate the distance from the rotation axis, by using a coefficient as simple friction simulation:

```
var dx = cartCX - wheelCX,
    dy = cartCY - wheelCY,
    dist = Math.sqrt(cartCX * wheelCX + cartCY * wheelCY);

var wheelRotation = Math.atan2(-dy, -dx) * dist * friction;
```

Consider following case:

1. the wheel is in a stable position, aligned with the rotation
   circumference of the car after a long-enough clock-wise rotation of the whole system.
2. now, the whole system is rotating CCW: then the swivel should lead
       some wheels perform an initial CCW-rotation (wheel
       right-top in the example picture) which shall be then adequately
       tweened until the wheel is aligned. Wheels left-top, left-bottom and right bottom shall be
       rotate CW.

Is there a simple way to calculate the rotation angles of the wheels without any phisics engine?

I don't need an exact physics rigid body simulation, just a simple swivel effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple swivels**

Assuming the wheels are casters.

To describe one

```
// ? for numbers save me making up numbers
var wheel = {
   swivel : {x : ?, y : ?}, // world position of swivel (rotation point 
   length : ?,  // distance from swivel to ground Contact when viewed from above
   angle : ?, // current angle
}
```

When the cart moves rotates and/or travel there is a local vector of movement at the wheels swivel

```
var delta = { x : ? , y : ? };
```

This movement is then applied in the reverse direction on the wheel where it contacts the ground.

```
var wheelForce = {};
wheelForce.x = -delta.x;
wheelForce.y = -delta.y;
```

There will be two types of motion on the wheel, one is rotation and one is translation. It is constrained by the swingarm so all we need is the rotation as translation will come from the movement of the cart.

First normalize the wheelForce

```
nwf = {};  // for (n)ormalised (w)heel (f)orce
var dist = Math.hypot(wheelForce.x,wheelForce.y);
nwf.x = wheelForce.x / dist;
nwf.y = wheelForce.y / dist;
```

Then get the normalised vector from the swivel to the wheel ground contact point

```
var dir = {};
dir.x = Math.cos(wheel.angle);
dir.y = Math.sin(wheel.angle);
```

Then get the sin of the angle between nwf and dir using cross product

```
var fs = nwf.x * dir.y - nwf.y * dir.x;
```

Now just get the angle from the inverse sin and rotate the wheel by that amount.

```
wheel.angle -= Math.asin(fs); // I never get this right (may have to subtract, been up to long to think this out see demo)
```

**UPDATE**

OP has requested some improvements. Skip the line above Update

To allow for the wheels to slip (or turn) will reduce the turning force on the swivel.

THe amount of slipping is related to the cos of the angle between the wheelForce and wheel directions. If the angle is 0 then cos will return 1 meaning the wheels are totally free to roll / slip, if the wheel direction is at 90 deg to the force then they will not turn (like dragging a car sideways) cos 90 return 0

But if we allow for the wheels to turn completely without resistance then that does not work well. So with a limiting factor this modification will improve the sim.

Thus calculate the slip amount

```
    var wheelTurnResistance = 0.8;
    var slip = Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.asin(fs))) * wheelTurnResistance;
```

Now apply the turning force reduced to account for the slip, I have also added an extra reduction to ease the speed of rotation

```
    var beNiceFactor = 0.6; // this further reduces the tendency to turn valid values 1-0 where smaller number reduce the tendency to swivel
    wheel.angle -= Math.asin(fs) * Math.abs(fs) * (1 - slip) * beNiceFactor;
```

Will also add this to the demo code below.

That is as far as this method will allow. If you want a better sim we will have to start from scratch and use a more complex solution

That is it.

**DEMO**

It seams way to simple so had to try it in code, Below is a demo using the above method. You could improve it by limiting the amount you add the the wheel angle, Multiplying by the sin of the angle you add makes it a little less responsive, and to add slippage just multiply by another fraction.

Thus where the wheel angle is changed in the function updateTrolly change

```
ww.angle -= Math.asin(cross);
```

to

```
ww.angle -= Math.asin(cross) * Math.abs(cross) * 0.1;
```

where `Math.abs(cross)` is the positive sin of the angle added and `0.1` is the amount of slippage ( any value < 1 and > 0, with 1 no slippage)

Click and drag on or near the cart to move it. The wheels will follow.

The demo has an `updateTrolly` function that does the wheels, but is dependent on the wheel positions calculated in the `displayTrolly` function.

The code you are interested in starts about halfway down the rest just handles the mouse and canvas.

**DEMO UPDATED** See update in answer re slippage.

```js
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
const CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID = "canv";
const U = undefined;
var w, h, cw, ch; // short cut vars 
var canvas, ctx, mouse;
var globalTime = 0; 
var createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals;
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () {
    var c,cs;
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; 
    c.id = CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID;    
    cs.position = "absolute";
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
    cs.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(c); 
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); }
}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; }
mouse = (function(){
    function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0,
        over : false,  // mouse is over the element
        bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
        mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.offsetX; m.y = e.offsetY;
        if (m.x === U) { m.x = e.clientX; m.y = e.clientY; }
        m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
        else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
        else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
        else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
        else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
        else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
        if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
            else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
        } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
        m.element = element === U ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== U) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();
var done = function(){
    window.removeEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas)
    mouse.remove();
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);    
    canvas = ctx = mouse = U;
    L("All done!")
}

resizeCanvas(); // create and size canvas
mouse.start(canvas,true); // start mouse on canvas and block context menu
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); // add resize event


// ================================================================================
// Start of answer code

const SYSTEM_DRAG = 0.99; // add drag to stop everything flying around. value > 0 and < 1 the closer to 1 the less the drag (friction)
const MOUSE_FORCE = 600; // multiplies mouse movement force bigger number more force
const TROLLY_WIDTH = 100;
const TROLLY_LENGTH = 200;
const WHEEL_INSET = 0;
const WHEEL_WIDTH = 10;

const WHEEL_SWING_LENGTH = 20;
//const WHEEL_LENGTH = WHEEL_SWING_LENGTH * (2/3);
const WHEEL_LENGTH =30;
const PIXEL_MASS = 2; // mass per pixel. Need mass for better sim

var trolly = {
    wheels : [],
    x : 200, 
    y : 200,
    r : 0,
    dx : 0,
    dy : 0,
    dr : 0,
    w : TROLLY_WIDTH,
    l : TROLLY_LENGTH,
    mass : TROLLY_WIDTH * TROLLY_LENGTH * PIXEL_MASS
};
function addWheel(t,x,y,dist,angle){
    t.wheels.push({
        x:x,
        y:y, // relative to the trolly
        rx : x,  // to keep it simple r is for real worl position
        ry : y,
        lrx : x, // and lr is for last real world position. That will give delta at wheel
        lry : y,
        length : dist,
        angle : angle, // absolute angle relative to the world
    })
    t.mass += WHEEL_WIDTH * WHEEL_LENGTH * PIXEL_MASS;
}
addWheel(trolly,-(TROLLY_LENGTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),-(TROLLY_WIDTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),WHEEL_SWING_LENGTH, 0);
addWheel(trolly,(TROLLY_LENGTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),-(TROLLY_WIDTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),WHEEL_SWING_LENGTH, 0);
addWheel(trolly,(TROLLY_LENGTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),(TROLLY_WIDTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),WHEEL_SWING_LENGTH, 0);
addWheel(trolly,-(TROLLY_LENGTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),(TROLLY_WIDTH / 2 - WHEEL_INSET),WHEEL_SWING_LENGTH, 0);

function drawTrolly(t){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,t.x,t.y);
    ctx.rotate(t.r);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(-t.l/2,-t.w/2);
    ctx.lineTo(t.l/2,-t.w/2);
    ctx.lineTo(t.l/2,t.w/2);
    ctx.lineTo(-t.l/2,t.w/2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    var dx = Math.cos(t.r); // x axis
    var dy = Math.sin(t.r);
    for(var i = 0; i < t.wheels.length; i ++){
        var w = t.wheels[i];
        var x = w.x * dx + w.y * - dy; 
        var y = w.x * dy + w.y *  dx; 
        var wx = Math.cos(w.angle);  // vector to the wheel
        var wy = Math.sin(w.angle);
        w.lrx = w.rx;  // save last pos
        w.lry = w.ry;
        w.rx = t.x + x;  // save new pos
        w.ry = t.y + y;
        // get ground contact point 
        var gx = t.x + x + wx * w.length;
        var gy = t.y + y + wy * w.length;
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,w.rx, w.ry); // reset transform
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,gx,gy); // move to the wheel
        ctx.lineTo(0,0);
        ctx.rotate(w.angle);
        ctx.moveTo(-WHEEL_LENGTH / 2, -WHEEL_WIDTH / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(WHEEL_LENGTH / 2, -WHEEL_WIDTH / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(WHEEL_LENGTH / 2, WHEEL_WIDTH / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(-WHEEL_LENGTH / 2, WHEEL_WIDTH / 2);
        ctx.closePath();    
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
function updateTrolly(t){
    for(var i = 0; i < t.wheels.length; i ++){
        var ww = t.wheels[i];
        var dx = ww.rx - ww.lrx; // get delta change at wheels
        var dy = ww.ry - ww.lry;
        var dist = Math.hypot(dx,dy);
        if(dist > 0.00001){ // not to small to bother
            var nx = -dx / dist;
            var ny = -dy / dist;
            var wx = Math.cos(ww.angle);
            var wy = Math.sin(ww.angle);
            var cross = nx * wy - ny * wx;
            var slip = Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.asin(cross))) * 0.7;
            ww.angle -= Math.asin(cross) * Math.abs(cross) * (1-slip) * 0.6;
        }
    }
    t.x += t.dx;
    t.y += t.dy;
    t.r += t.dr;
    t.dx *= SYSTEM_DRAG;
    t.dy *= SYSTEM_DRAG;
    t.dr *= SYSTEM_DRAG;
    t.x = ((t.x % w) + w) % w; // keep onscreen
    t.y = ((t.y % h) + h) % h; // keep onscreen
    
}

function applyForceCenter(object, force, direction){ // force is a vector
    force /= object.mass; // now use F = m * a in the form a = F/m
    object.dx += Math.cos(direction) * force;
    object.dy += Math.sin(direction) * force;
}
function applyForce(object, force, direction, locx,locy){ // force is a vector, loc is a coordinate
    var radius = Math.hypot(object.y - locy, object.x - locx);
    if(radius <= 0.00001){
        applyForceCenter(object,force,direction);
        return;
    }
    var toCenter = Math.atan2(object.y - locy, object.x - locx);
    var pheta = toCenter - direction;
    var Fv = Math.cos(pheta) * force;
    var Fa = Math.sin(pheta) * force;
    Fv /= object.mass; // now use F = m * a in the form a = F/m
    var Fvx = Math.cos(toCenter) * Fv;
    var Fvy = Math.sin(toCenter) * Fv;
    object.dx += Fvx; 
    object.dy += Fvy;
    Fa /= (radius  * object.mass); // for the angular component get the rotation
                                                   // acceleration
    object.dr += Fa;// now add that to the box delta r
}
function applyForceToTrolly(t,x,y,dx,dy){
    var f = Math.hypot(dx,dy) * MOUSE_FORCE;
    var dir = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    applyForce(t,f,dir,x,y);
}

var lx,ly;
function display(){  // put code in here
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
        applyForceToTrolly(trolly,mouse.x,mouse.y,mouse.x-lx,mouse.y-ly);
        
    }
    updateTrolly(trolly);
    drawTrolly(trolly);
    lx = mouse.x;
    ly = mouse.y;
}
function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

Comment: Howewer, inverting the rotation from a stable position is too jumpy. If you start from a stable position and revert the direction of the rotation, the wheels angle is jumping immediately. I was also stuck thinking how to smooth revert the direction of the wheels. Do you have an idea how to tween the motion reversal? A wheel should be aligned with the cart after a cart rotation of, let say, between 30 and 45 degrees. What you think about that?

Comment: @deblocker The solution I gave does not take into account the fact that the wheels can go round. Its like the brakes are on. You can add some movement to the wheels (release the brake) its just like allowing some slippage.  Do up to steps where you find `fs` in the answer then multiply the wheelForce vector by `1 - Math.cos(Math.asin(fs))` this will reduce the strength of wheelForce, then do the steps again from normalise wheelForce. That is of the top of my head, will check when I get a chance.

Comment: @deblocker skip that last comment. I will add a change to the answer, it will allow some slippage along the wheel direction with a limiting factor and is just a simple change. It may solve your problems